# JQuery Autocomplete - Prevent destruction of items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete box with a 'large' (about 500) array as inline source. When clicked on the input box I do a search("") to make the whole list visible. This takes about 2 seconds to generate due to the 500 items.

JQuery's autocomplete creates and destroys these items on every click / search and would be a lot faster if these items would be re-used.

Is there a way to do this (using jquery's built-in autocomplete)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the source code of the [autocomplete](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/autocomplete.js) widget I came to the conclusion that this isn't possible.

The function `_suggest` has as first line `var ul = this.menu.element.empty()`, it would require a big overhaul in the source code to make this possible:

1. You need to create a new function that will generate all the items when the page is loading. (Which might increase negatively the loading time of your website.)
2. You need to adjust the `_render` functions so that they also will filter items with show/hide class rather then rendering them.

I think your best option is generating the autocomplete as plain HTML (without JS) and write your own hide/show function. You could also of course look for a plugin that tackled this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. If requested by my users I'll write my own indeed. Till that time.. it will do.